# How to access namespaces in a DLL via another DLL?

Tags: c#, dll

I have multiple DLLs (either managed myself or not managed myself) that I would like to include in a CoreLib.dll so that I do not have to include (possibly) hundreds of DLLs in every application that uses these DLLs. I include the DLLs with a reference directly to the DLL.

So, I would also like to instantiate classes declared within those DLLs in the application I am creating. I cannot do what is pictured in MyApp.exe project, even though I would like to.  There is no reference to A, B or C in CoreLib.

[image]

How can I accomplish what I want?

EDIT
I used Facade Pattern as suggested, however I am getting a compilation error.  Its saying I have to include A.dll in MyApp project.  Why?  This is what I wanted to avoid.  Any way around this?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is duplicate but it might get you somewhere... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307602/understanding-ilmerge-how-to-pack-an-executable-with-all-its-associated-dlls

Comment: How do you plan to know the types in those various dlls?

Comment: You may be attempting a plug-in architecture: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071265/plugin-architecture-dependency-injection-question

Comment: I can obtain the types that are available in my A, B, C dlls by knowing the namespace, and letting auto complete tell me what is available.  I do not want a plug-in architecture though.  I just dont want to have 100s of DLLs, I would like to merge into one DLL, and not use ILMerge which will merge the DLLs and the EXE into one EXE.  I want to be able to reuse the CoreLib dll, and possibly give the dll to other people so they can use it as well.

Comment: @Tizz ILMerge can merge the dlls into another dll! You just tell it to output a dll - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is possible. Adding reference to A, B and C DLLs in CorLib will only mean that CorLib references these DLLs (AssemblyRef metadata table will have one record for each assembly). This does not mean CorLib redefines the assemblies and any types of the referenced assemblies. in MyApp.exe, you would need to reference A, B and C assemblies.

An alternative solution would be to define a Facade class in CorLib and redirect calls to A, B and C DLLs. In MyApp.exe, you will use the Facade class.

Comment: I like the idea of using a Facade class, however, what if I have static methods in classes?  I cannot bring over the static method (or static classes for that matter).

Comment: You can redefine the methods in Facade class and then delegate the call to original method\class. Static\Instance method will not make any difference.

Comment: So I did all of this (which took a while because there are many methods and classes and variables, and now its saying that MyApp.exe projects needs to reference A.dll. This is what I was trying to avoid in the first place. Any ideas what I did wrong? Or did not do?  Ive updated my question above.

Comment: I think the client will need to reference A and B DLLs. But client will not need to access any class from A or B DLLs. Client will only need to interact with your Facade class. This is similar to Enterprise Library Exception Handling and Logging blocks. When logging some information or handling some exception using Enterprise Library application blocks, client will only need to interact with Facade class (e.g. Logger) but client needs to reference all the DLLs used by the block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630) to merge the assemblies into one.

Then you can use all the classes in that assembly the way you want to.

Here's an example how to merge several assemblies (dlls) into one assembly (dll):
http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/01/ilmerge-to-combine-multiple-dlls.html

Essentaily you just do

```
ILMerge.exe /out:CoreLib.dll A.dll B.dll C.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing DLL (which is in native managed world contain actual implementation) with LIB/OBJ files that contain something that will be merged into EXE/DLL at build time to include implementation into corresponding EXE/DLL.

You have essentially 2 options:

- carry all DLLs with your application (normal approach, should be taken unless you have strange requirements). You can either reference assemblies directly from your main application and create classes or make some sort of factory in your CoreLib assembly that will create classes on demand. In later case you may not need to add references to all A..C assemblies (if you not using classes directly, but via some shared interfaces/base classes), but still need to carry them around.
- some sort of merging assemblies into one (i.e. ILMerge as suggested by @Alex). This approach would require better understanding of CLR than first one and may not be possible if third party assemblies are involved (due to licensing).