# Accessing Properties.Settings from DLL

Tags: c#, dll

I have an application which has a `Properties.Settings` class, filled with `user` scope strings. I have a DLL which needs to read and write said strings from the DLL itself. How can I access `Myapp.Properties.Settings` from this DLL?

Is there a way I can pass it as a delegate to the DLL? Thanks!

Comment: Where is this DLL? is it of same namespace?

Comment: @Prajwal It will be of a different namespace. However if they are in the same namespace, how would I access Settings as well?

Comment: `Resources.Properties.Settings.Default.<name>`?

Comment: @Prajwal Sorry I am new to Windows development. When you say same namespace, do you mean if the namespace of my Settings is the same namespace as the class in the DLL I'm calling Settings from? In my case, the namespaces will be different.

Comment: Actually I use that Settings in the applications I've done as well. But it will be in same namespace. At that time we can directly refer it. I never used it  in different namespace.

Comment: But I guess, you can just refer that namespace in DLL, like `Namespace.Resources`

Comment: @Prajwal Thanks for your help Prajwal. But I can't hardcode the namespace of my application into the DLL. Does anyone know a way where I can get the namespace of the application from the DLL by code? Or in a way, get a reference that application from DLL?

Comment: This might help. Check it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826084/how-to-access-namespaces-in-a-dll-via-another-dll?rq=1